# How to populate a Multiple Select with fixed option in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have an edit.blade.php ( User Profile ) where I have a multiple Select that should show fixed options. when i Edit the profile for the first time, i receive error.

Error :

```
Call to a member function toArray() on null (View: /Users/mnamazi/Sites/localhost/serresokhan/resources/views/panel/profile/edit.blade.php)
```

edit.blade.php :

```
<div class="col-xl-6">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="favorite">علاقمند شرکت در مسابقه</label>
         <select name="favorite[]" class="form-control kt-selectpicker @error('favorite') is-invalid @enderror" multiple>
             <option @if(in_array(1, $user->favorite)->toArray()) selected @endif value="1">گویندگی</option>
             <option @if(in_array(2, $user->favorite)->toArray()) selected @endif value="2">اجرا</option>
             <option @if(in_array(3, $user->favorite)->toArray()) selected @endif value="3">سخنوری</option>
         </select>
         @error('favorite')
            <div class="invalid-feedback"> {{ $message }}</div>
         @enderror
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of `@if(in_array(1, $user->favorite)->toArray())` you probably meant `@if(in_array(1, $user->favorite->toArray()))`

Comment: I tested this before, I still get the same error

Comment: probably `$user->favorite` is null?

Comment: if Edit the profile for the first time, yes Null it.

Comment: i need show fixed items in list for first time, but when User select favorites Option, show selected item ( Checked Item ).

Comment: @MNamazi Is `favorite` a column in the users table or is it a relation on the user table? Can you please share this info to help better?

Comment: @Abishek `favorite` is a column of users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the purpose of the `in_array` and `->toArray()` is for as there is not much information on if the `favorite` is a column or a relation on the model.

If the `favorite` is a column on the `users` table, then you can try

```
<div class="col-xl-6">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="favorite">علاقمند شرکت در مسابقه</label>
         <select name="favorite[]" class="form-control kt-selectpicker @error('favorite') is-invalid @enderror" multiple>
             <option @if($user->favorite == 1) selected @endif value="1">گویندگی</option>
             <option @if($user->favorite == 2) selected @endif value="2">اجرا</option>
             <option @if($user->favorite == 3) selected @endif value="3">سخنوری</option>
         </select>
         @error('favorite')
            <div class="invalid-feedback"> {{ $message }}</div>
         @enderror
     </div>
</div>
```

But if it is a relation on the model, then

```
<div class="col-xl-6">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="favorite">علاقمند شرکت در مسابقه</label>
             <select name="favorite[]" class="form-control kt-selectpicker @error('favorite') is-invalid @enderror" multiple>
                 <option @if($user->favorite->id == 1) selected @endif value="1">گویندگی</option>
                 <option @if($user->favorite->id == 2) selected @endif value="2">اجرا</option>
                 <option @if($user->favorite->id == 3) selected @endif value="3">سخنوری</option>
             </select>
             @error('favorite')
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> {{ $message }}</div>
             @enderror
         </div>
    </div>
```

Based on your comment that it is an array, you can try this.

Please make sure you have the `favorite` cast to an array on your model.

```
public class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
       'favorite'=>'array',
    ];
}
```

Once this is done, Laravel will automatically cast the `favorite` attribute into an array and can be accessed on your view using `in_array`.

```
<div class="col-xl-6">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="favorite">علاقمند شرکت در مسابقه</label>
         <select name="favorite[]" class="form-control kt-selectpicker @error('favorite') is-invalid @enderror" multiple>
             <option @if(in_array(1,$user->favorite)) selected @endif value="1">گویندگی</option>
             <option @if(in_array(2,$user->favorite)) selected @endif value="2">اجرا</option>
             <option @if(in_array(3,$user->favorite)) selected @endif value="3">سخنوری</option>
         </select>
         @error('favorite')
            <div class="invalid-feedback"> {{ $message }}</div>
         @enderror
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. error solved but dont show ( checked ) saved items !

Comment: `$user->favorite->id == 1` its array ? Because data saved in database like `["1"]` or like `["2","3"]`

Comment: @MNamazi, added an additional code based on your comment about the `favorite` column

Comment: Thank you, my problem was solved with your help

Answer (score 0):

i changed `name` of select to `favoriteMain` but get this error :

```
in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given
```

my code is :

```
<div class="col-xl-4">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="favoriteMain">اصلی</label>
         <select name="favoriteMain[]" class="form-control kt-selectpicker @error('favoriteMain') is-invalid @enderror" multiple>
               <option @if(in_array(1,$user->favoriteMain)) selected @endif value="1">اجرای صحنه</option>
               <option @if(in_array(2,$user->favoriteMain)) selected @endif value="2">اجرای تلوزیون</option>
               <option @if(in_array(3,$user->favoriteMain)) selected @endif value="3">اجرای رادیویی - صدا</option>
               <option @if(in_array(4,$user->favoriteMain)) selected @endif value="4">هم زبانان ( بین الملل )</option>
         </select>
     @error('favoriteMain')
         <div class="invalid-feedback"> {{ $message }}</div>
     @enderror
</div>
```